# How do I install Java 5?

Tags: java, 9.10

I followed the **approach** for **Ubuntu 9.10**, to install java 5 but it is saying after executing the command update,

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

and some times,

Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

**approach:**

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates multiverse
```

save the file and close gedit. Next sync your sources by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java5-
```

Comment: I have to agree with fossfreedom. You should really upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu. You don't have to upgrade to Natty. If you want to be stable and relatively up to date you should go for 10.04 the latest LTS. Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 1):

Support for Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty has ended on 23 October 2010. No updates will be released for that version. The repositories for this version has also been removed.

You need to upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version - recommend doing a clean install.

If you dont want to upgrade, you can download the sources and compile yourself.